# How to create a encrypt writer and decrypt reader in C#

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, xml-serialization

I am currently using XML Serialization to serialize a class instance.

I like to create an encrypt StreamWriter to replace steamwriter. Is this a good way to do it?   If not what should I do?

```
public class PO po = new PO ();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
serializer.Serialize(writer, po);
```

Answer (score 0):

`StreamWriter` is basically a wrapper around stream that provides additional APIs to convert from typed values (e.g. strings) to binary. As encryption often does not require knowledge of input encoding or any information other then just binary data, I would say an encrypted `Stream` (wrapping normal `Stream`) is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CryptoStream` class which defines a stream that links data streams to cryptographic transformations. You can find an example in the following link: http://www.obviex.com/Samples/Encryption.aspx

Comment: How would you decrypt what you encrypt?